# Escrita em arquivo binário

Tags: c++, arquivo

Como faço para escrever em uma posição qualquer de um arquivo binário usando a biblioteca fstream, sem sobrescrever o conteúdo já inserido no arquivo?
  Comecei tentando assim:

```
    ofstream salvar;
    salvar.open(arq_dados,ios::binary);
    salvar.seekp(sizeof(structGenerica) * posicaoArquivo );
    salvar.write((const char*)(&structAux), sizeof(structGenerica));
    salvar.close();
```

Também tentei usar a flag ios :: app que também não funcionou.

Comment: O que já tentou? É um bom passo para que possamos entender justamente onde está sua dúvida. Na real, seria apenas evitar abrir o arquivo como escrita apenas, talvez o que se deseja seja o modo de `append` ou `read+`, que permite também escrita

Comment: o ideal é editar a questão, depois no máximo me marcar no comentário para eu ver a atualização.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Sobrescrevendo registros em arquivo binário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304092/sobrescrevendo-registros-em-arquivo-bin%c3%a1rio)

Comment: @Articuno , realmente ,esqueci de apagar a outra pergunta , obrigado

Comment: @RaphaelRoriz ficar apagando questões é ruim, muito ruim. Melhor tentar salvar do que criar novas cópias, e a outra questão tinha salvação. Fica a dica

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está se atentando aos modos de abertura do arquivo na chamada do construtor de `std::ofstream` e na posição de referência passado como parametro ao método `std::ofstream::seekp()`.

Segue uma função capaz de gravar uma estrutura "genérica" em um arquivo binário:

```
void gravar_arquivo( void * p, std::size_t n, const char * arq, long pos = -1 )
{
    if( pos == -1 )
    {
        // Apenas inclui um novo registro no final do arquivo (append)
        std::ofstream ofs( arq, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out | std::ios::app );
        ofs.write( (char*) p, n );
        ofs.close();
    }
    else
    {
        // Grava em uma posicao especifica do arquivo
        std::ofstream ofs( arq, std::ios::binary| std::ios::out | std::ios::in );
        ofs.seekp( n * pos, std::ios::beg );
        ofs.write( (char*) p, n );
        ofs.close();
    }
}
```

Programa para geração de um arquivo binário de teste chamado `saida.bin` contendo `5` registros:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>


typedef struct foobar_s
{
    char id;
    char text[16];
} foobar_t;


void gravar_arquivo( void * p, std::size_t n, const char * arq, long pos = -1 )
{
    if( pos == -1 )
    {
        // Apenas inclui um novo registro no final do arquivo (append)
        std::ofstream ofs( arq, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out | std::ios::app );
        ofs.write( (char*) p, n );
        ofs.close();
    }
    else
    {
        // Grava em uma posicao especifica do arquivo
        std::ofstream ofs( arq, std::ios::binary| std::ios::out | std::ios::in );
        ofs.seekp( n * pos, std::ios::beg );
        ofs.write( (char*) p, n );
        ofs.close();
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    foobar_t fb[5];

    /* Preenche 5 registros */
    fb[0].id = 1; std::strcpy( fb[0].text, "Alpha" );
    fb[1].id = 2; std::strcpy( fb[1].text, "Beta" );
    fb[2].id = 3; std::strcpy( fb[2].text, "Gamma" );
    fb[3].id = 4; std::strcpy( fb[3].text, "Delta" );
    fb[4].id = 5; std::strcpy( fb[4].text, "Episilon" );

    /* Grava sequenciamente os 5 registro em arquivo binario */
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        gravar_arquivo( (void*) &fb[i], sizeof(foobar_t), "saida.bin" );

    return 0;
}
```

Arquivo gerado `saida.bin`:

```
0000000: 0141 6c70 6861 0000 2699 33af 4d7f 0000  .Alpha..&.3.M...
0000010: 0102 4265 7461 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..Beta..........
0000020: 0100 0347 616d 6d61 0018 75ae 4d7f 0000  ...Gamma..u.M...
0000030: 0100 0004 4465 6c74 6100 4000 0000 0000  ....Delta.@.....
0000040: 0000 0000 0545 7069 7369 6c6f 6e00 0000  .....Episilon...
0000050: 700b 4000 00                             p.@..
```

Agora, um programa capaz de alterar apenas o `Quarto` registro contido no arquivo `saida.bin`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>


typedef struct foobar_s
{
    char id;
    char text[16];
} foobar_t;


void gravar_arquivo( void * p, std::size_t n, const char * arq, long pos = -1 )
{
    if( pos == -1 )
    {
        // Apenas inclui um novo registro no final do arquivo (append)
        std::ofstream ofs( arq, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out | std::ios::app );
        ofs.write( (char*) p, n );
        ofs.close();
    }
    else
    {
        // Grava em uma posicao especifica do arquivo
        std::ofstream ofs( arq, std::ios::binary| std::ios::out | std::ios::in );
        ofs.seekp( n * pos, std::ios::beg );
        ofs.write( (char*) p, n );
        ofs.close();
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    foobar_t fb;

    fb.id = 99;
    std::strcpy( fb.text, "Omega" );

    gravar_arquivo( (void*) &fb, sizeof(foobar_t), "saida.bin", 3 );

    return 0;
}
```

Arquivo **modificado** `saida.bin`:

```
0000000: 0141 6c70 6861 0000 2699 33af 4d7f 0000  .Alpha..&.3.M...
0000010: 0102 4265 7461 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ..Beta..........
0000020: 0100 0347 616d 6d61 0018 75ae 4d7f 0000  ...Gamma..u.M...
0000030: 0100 0063 4f6d 6567 6100 0000 0840 0000  ...cOmega....@..
0000040: 0000 00c0 0545 7069 7369 6c6f 6e00 0000  .....Episilon...
0000050: 700b 4000 00                             p.@..
```